# Powershell command to format the usb drive even though a file was opened

Tags: powershell

I need to format a USB drive even though the file was opened. Need to have a powershell command which need to execute using java program.

Currently, we are using, **powershell.exe format /FS:FAT32 E: /Q /v:Volume Name**

The above command works fine, but it does not format when any of files from USB drive oepned. I wanted to force format eventhough the files were opened.

Can anyone help if any powershell command exists which would force format?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the Microsoft docs for the **format** command ([Format | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/format)) what you want can be indirectly solved by using the */x* parameter which

> Causes the volume to dismount, if necessary, before it is formatted. Any open handles to the volume will no longer be valid.

Comment: thanks for your response. my current one also work even though files were opened. we will consider this option if we face an issue.